# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and JSON in Postgres

Tags: java, json, spring, postgresql

Is it possible to insert json into a postgresql json column using the `NamedParameterJDBCTemplate` class in SpringFramework and I am getting a `PSQLException: No hstore extension installed.` From this I gather that the `NamedParameterJDBCTemplate`is trying to store the value as hstore.

Is there a way I can tell the `NamedParameterJDBCTemplate` to insert the value into the query as json?

The value is stored in java as a `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me to insert Map as jsonb using namedjdbctemplate.

1. Create json_string from Map using jackson library or GSON can be used.
2. Create PGObject and fill with value like below.
3. Use the  PGObject in your SQL prepare statement.

Hope this helps.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();
String Map_Json_String = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(your_map);
jsonObject.setType("jsonb");
jsonObject.setValue(Map_Json_String);

String final insertSql = "INSERT INTO \"Table_Name\""
            + " VALUES (:jsonObject);";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Put STRING, cast to JSONB, in sql

Add `::JSONB` suffix to your SQL parameter.

Set the formatted string value, not a Map:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(""
    + "INSERT INTO my_table              "
    + "        (my_jsonb_column)         "
    + " VALUES (:my_jsonb_column::JSONB) ",

    Map.of("my_jsonb_column", "{\"my_key\": \"my value!\"}"));
```

---

## In **Spring**

In Spring "you" usually convert "your" HashMaps to (json) strings using ObjectMapper:

```
    Map.of("my_jsonb_column", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(yourMap))
```

NOTE: Posgres' JsonB only supports Bool, Number, and Text values. So convert nested objects, if any, to string recursively.